# Bracket notation for discontinuous trees

Tags: constituents

Formally representing constituency based structures, using brackets to denote constituents, is straight-forward - until discontinuities are thrown in the mix.

Consider this example, adapted from [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discontinuity_(linguistics)):

> Sarah tutors John

Which could, for the sake of argument, be bracketed as follows:

> { {Sarah} {tutors {John } } }

By means of WH-fronting, we could easily turn this sentence into:

> Who has Sarah been tutoring?

Visually representing this is quite easy - you simply cross some lines on a piece of paper (example, again, pilfered from Wikipeda):

[image]

How would you go about representing it via a bracketing system, though?

Comment: Why not represent 'movement' as actual movement? [MIles Shang's Syntree](http://mshang.ca/syntree/) does this to some extent: try entering *[? [text [S  [np [Who_A]] [aux.inv [aux [has_B]] [vp [np.su Sarah][vp.prf [auxHAVE.3s _<B>][vp.prg  [auxBE.pa.ppl been][vp  [v.pr.ppl tutoring][np.do _<A>]]]]]]]] [punc ?]]*.

Comment: Hmm...I don't believe this solves the problem. This simply rearranges the tree.

Comment: Fersher. Depends on your theory: does it hold that what's "actually" there is a discontinuity or that what's there is "actually" a displacement-and-gap? Bracketing is designed for the latter.

Comment: What is "displacement-and-gap"?

Comment: There is no movement to speak of in my case. I'm coming from a computational perspective - generating training data for sentence parsers. I need to formally represent discontinuous surface structures.

Comment: Bracketing presupposes that there is no discontinuity. To accommodate discontinuity you need some sort of anaphoric device which correlates an existing remote constituent and a local 'empty' constituent. After that it's just a matter of telling your parser how to represent that, whether as line crossing or movement arrows or some other convention.

Comment: Thought as much :)  Are you aware of any literature that explicitly discusses this limitation? Would love to read up more. Also please add your comments as answer. I'd like to accept it.

Comment: I'm strictly an amateur in this, winging it for my own purposes, so most of the literature I've encountered is too technically formalized for me to judge its validity; and the notations and formalizations are tied to specific theories/approaches I'm usually unfamiliar with. (Your notation, for instance, where a word acts as its own parent, is very odd to me!) Consequently I'm not comfortable putting up an Answer, as if I actually knew what I was talking about.

Comment: That Wiki tree is wacko -- and why is the subject 'Sarah' shown as part of the predicate?  Nested brackets can only represent 'flat' trees.  Perhaps something like { {1:Whom}{2:has} { {Sarah}{_2_{been{tutoring{_1_}}}} } } to show the displacements, but is this ever useful?

Comment: Sorry, my attempts to use underlines for the traced items triggered italics...